# Nativescript problems migrating from NS 2 to 3

Tags: nativescript

Trying to migrate my app from 2 to 3 on android.

I downloaded all the new requirements. Tested environment on a newly template created project and works fine.

In my project, I updated the tsconfig.js file and fixed a few error messages.

These are what I'm left with mainly - errors like:

Property 'NSObject' does not exist on type 'Global'

All have to do with Global.

In code I have it like global.NSObject

but "global" seems to be defined in NS 3.0 - in tns-core-modules/modules.d.ts.

but there's no field for NSobject  - ergo the error.

Am I supposed to use global.__native.NSObject???

Also, I've got a worker thread and seems like the signature changed.

Getting errors for onmessage and also the signature of postMessage() seems to have changed - no updates in docs.

`global.onmessage = function(msg) {}`

Help appreciated as always.

My package.json file

```
{
    "description": "NativeScript Application",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
    "readme": "NativeScript Application",
    "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
    "nativescript": {
        "id": "dev.myapp.test",
        "tns-android": {
            "version": "3.2.0"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.7",
        "tns-core-modules": "^3.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-traverse": "6.19.0",
        "babel-types": "6.19.0",
        "babylon": "6.14.1",
        "lazy": "1.0.11",
        "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.7",
        "typescript": "~2.2.1"
    }
}
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
                "./node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms",
        "**/*.aot.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The Worker API has had no changes since it was first released. Please make sure you are using the proper definitions file from the cross-platform modules.

Comment: I think the issue is with typescript definition somewhere and something is not updated. But I did upgrade to latest ts 2.2.2. I've posted my package and tsconfig file above.

Comment: I did notice that my "nativescript-dev-typescript" wasn't updated to 0.5.0. btw what's the difference between the ~ and ^ prefix. I tried tns update <name> - and it updated to 0.3.7 only.

Comment: That's semversioning - or how you describe desired version ranges of npm packages. You can learn more at https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning or use the version calculator to play around with semver - https://semver.npmjs.com/